# Cannont install pymesh

Tags: python, pip, python-import

I installed pymesh using pip but it gives me this error. Pls help

```
>>> import pymesh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pymesh
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymesh2-0.1.14-py3.5-win32.egg\pymesh\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .Mesh import Mesh
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymesh2-0.1.14-py3.5-win32.egg\pymesh\Mesh.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PyMesh
ImportError: No module named 'PyMesh'
```

Comment: Check if the pymesh package got installed or not in the location`/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/pymesh`. Your issue is mostly because you installed pymesh in one version of python in your system, and you are trying to import it from another version of python of your system.

Comment: `pipx.x install pymesh` for your desired version.

Comment: I can see the pymesh package in the "site-packages" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the problem was that there were two versions of pymesh installed. So I deleted both of them and pip installed again. Then it fixed the error!